# AS3 Setup Buttons for All Frames in Document Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm making a simple interface with Flash. Let's say we've got:

frame 1: 1 button that advances to frame 10 (**goto10**)

frame 10: 2 buttons, one advances to frame 20 (**goto20**), one opens a URL (**openURL**)

frame 20: 3 buttons, one goes back to frame 1 (**goto1**), one goes to frame 10 (**goto10**), and one opens a URL (**openURL**)

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;

public class NKE_DocumentClass extends MovieClip {
    public var goto1:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton();
    public var goto10:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton();
    public var goto20:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton();
    public var openURL:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton();

    public function NKE_DocumentClass() {   
        goto1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(self:MouseEvent):void{clickGo(self,1)});
        goto10.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(self:MouseEvent):void{clickGo(self,10)});
        goto20.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(self:MouseEvent):void{clickGo(self,20)});
        openURL.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function(self:MouseEvent):void{urlGo(self,"http://google.com")});
        }

    public function clickGo(event:MouseEvent, nextCue:int):void {
        gotoAndStop(nextCue);
        trace("Advanced to: " + nextCue);
        }

    public function urlGo(event:MouseEvent, goURL:String):void {
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(goURL);
        new URLLoader(request);
        trace("Executed URL: " + goURL);
        }

}

}
```

Problem is, once I leave frame 1, none of the buttons work... they're simply unresponsive. It seems like the code doesn't stay loaded once it leaves frame 1.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pressuming the problem is because when this code is first executed (as a Document Class) the only button that exists is the button on frame 1? This is under the assumption than you've created buttons in the Flash IDE then added them to the stage from the library on the specific keyframes.

I see you've created the SimpleButtons programmatically but since they haven't been added to the stage in the code you've shown, the presumption is that you've just called them the same names as the buttons you've placed on stage? Correct me if I'm wrong and I'll try to offer some other advice if the below doesn't help.

One solution would be to create them all on the first frame then switch their visibility on and off depending on when you need them.

If you're not sure how:

```
goto10.visible = false;
```

etc etc

I can't remember now without testing but if you have placed them all on the stage on different keyframes this may cause a problem.

Back in the days of putting code on the timeline if you put code on frame 1 but it referenced objects that weren't on frame 1 then the code would fail (this is probably what's happening with your document class - it's running when not all objects exist).

I would make sure they're all on one layer without any keyframes, from frame 1,  and you just switch their visibility on and off. Alternatively, let your classes add and remove the buttons and other interface elements and don't use the timeline at all.